# How to achieve type-safety for primitive types without performance impact?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, type-safety

I would like the c compiler to check the usage of simple types. My preferred usage would be checking `typedef`s, but that is not done even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float deg;
typedef float rad;

float sinus( rad angle ) {
    return sin( angle );
}

int main() {
    deg a = 180;
    printf( "The sinus of %g is %g\n", a, sinus(a));
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without a hitch.

So I'm considering using one-member structures:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { float value; } deg;
typedef struct { float value; } rad;

float sinus( rad angle ) {
    return sin( angle.value );
}

int main() {
    deg a = {.value=180};
    printf( "The sinus of %g is %g\n", a, sinus(a));
    return 0;
}
```

This gives an outright error (as it should). However, I'm wondering about the performance. If I correct the above examples, the produced binaries have the same size, with optimization or without. However, the produced assembly differs. Can the compiler optimize out the `struct`, even in more complicated contexts? If not, is there another way to achieve type-safety for primitive types?

I'm using GCC (9.1.0), but I'd consider llvm if that helps. This is supposed to work for common desktop architectures, i.e. x86, x86_64, ARM.

Edit: I noticed you could also use `union` instead of `struct` in the above example. This again produces slightly different assembly code and again I'm not clear on the real world performance consequences.

Comment: This depends a lot on the ABI of the target architecture of your compiler. x86-64 is not the same as ARM-64 bits. This also depends upon your compilation options. With recent [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), did you try to compile *and link* [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -flto` ?

Comment: I'm on GCC 9.1.0 where `-Wextra` does not help. The change log for GCC 10 does not mention warnings for typedefs.

Comment: If you email me, please give some budget. My opinion is that at least 50k€ is required, and perhaps 3x more. But I am on holidays right now and could be *very wrong*

Answer (score 2):

> I would like the c compiler to check the usage of simple types. My preferred usage would be checking typedefs, but that is not done

A possible approach with a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) might be to add your extra `__attribute__` on your typedefs (or `#pragma`-s) and to code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing the checks (perhaps using both [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) and [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) techniques)

Notice that the features you want are beyond the semantics of standard C, as defined in e.g. [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf).

If permitted (and funded), I might extend (in spring 2021) the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static analyzer (described in this [DRAFT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) towards your goals. See also [CHARIOT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects.

An alternative approach is to design your own programming language, and to write your compiler [generating C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065). Then [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conferences are relevant.

Or adapt [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) for your needs.

In all cases, budget several months of specialized software engineers labor. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

### The checks you are dreaming of could be *partly* automated, but requires costly development.

Your question is related to [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis): a distance in meters divided by a duration in seconds gives a speed. And also to units (angles can be in radian and in degrees)

IIRC, some spacecraft has been lost because of such mistakes.

Comment: I realize this check is not required by standard C (though I don't understand why there shouldn't be at least a `strict typedef` for this functionality), but that's what compiler options are for, no?

Comment: Consider contributing to the C standardization process to push such features into future standards

Comment: How feasible is that for Joe C. Random?

Comment: It depends upon your education and your software engineering skills.

Comment: Or get someone already prominent in the standardization to promote this idea :D